# Using the $.widget factory to override jQuery UI Autocomplete options

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, widget, overriding

I decided to write a custom widget that extends and overrides the standard Autocomplete widget.

[The official documentation for the $.widget factory](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138135/Widget-factory) mentions inheritance, but it doesn't look like it's possibile to override the original widget options (i.e. not just add to them).

For example, I wasn't able to redefine the *source* option (that defaults to null) with this code:

```
$.widget("ui.productSearch", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    bla: 15,
    source: function( request, response ) {
       response($.ui.autocomplete
                .filter(["a", "b", "c"],request.term));
    },
    minLength: 2        
});
```

I tried out the above code [on JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/uzobo4/5/). If you inspect the resulting widget you can see that *bla* is added to the options, but both *source* and *minLength* still reflect the default values defined in $.ui.autocomplete. *source* is still null, and thus an error is raised: *this.source is not a function*.

What am I doing wrong? And if this is the expected behavior of $.widget, what is the best way to override an option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, looks to me like you're just defining a function 'source' in the new widget; that's fine, but you haven't overridden the option. What if you tried

```
$.widget("ui.productSearch", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    options: {
        bla: 15,
        source: function( request, response ) {
           response($.ui.autocomplete
                .filter(["a", "b", "c"],request.term));
        },
        minLength: 2
    }
});
```

?

Comment: I had completely missed that... Thank you!

Comment: That documentation is impenetrable. Plenty of docs on how to write the widget, NO documentation on how to instantiate it with custom values. For instance, I have a combobox widget where I want to pass it specific values so that I can set up a JSON source. But NOWHERE can I see how to call the blasted thing with a value.